# Find cell value in another sheet and change to that cell interior color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to have the selected cell on sheet1 (or every 8+11nth cell in column F to end) turn into the same interior color as the same value on sheet2 row2.

This is what I have so far. It's able to go to sheet2, but have trouble finding where the same value is at and selecting it.

```
Sub FindAndColor()

OA=ActiveCell.Address
rngY=ActiveCell.Value

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Rows(2).Select
    Selection.find(What:=rngY, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
      
ActiveCell.Select
CC=ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
OA.Select
ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color=CC

End Sub
```

Comment: `rngY=ActuveCell.Value` typo in active.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, typed it out wrong here.

Comment: Try it with a few practical examples: Let's say the used range on `Sheet1` is `A1:J10`. What should happen if `A1`, `C5` or `J10` are selected?

Answer (score 1):

When using `Find()` you should test whether a match was made before proceeding.

So something like this should work:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindAndColor()

    Dim f As Range, c As Range
    
    Set c = ActiveCell
    Set f = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(2).Find( _
                What:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
                
    If Not f Is Nothing Then 'found a match ?
        c.Interior.Color = f.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color 'DisplayFormat is read-only...
    Else
        'do something if no match?
    End If

End Sub
```